# Best way to get a file's path and paste it in a text file

Tags: javascript, html, path, outlook, text-files

I am trying to write a program, or HTML page actually, with 3 inputs, Firstname, Lastname, and Date, and a OK button. It should look for the file with those three inputs as a file name (ie.: John_Smith_22AUG13.pdf) inside of an specific folder (ie. C:\Test\John_Smith_22AUG13.pdf) and if it exists copy the path to the clipboard so the user can then paste it in an email.
I was wondering if someone has done something similar in the past and has any advice or programming language I should use to do this.
Can this be done using javascript? If not what else could I use?

Anything helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken, but as this is within a webpage I believe you can't get direct access to the file system of the users computer. This would open a number of security holes, and that would be bad. So from within a webapp, I don't believe that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist and try out the

```
<input type="file">
```

kind of way and handle the chosen file in a JS method. As brandon-gardiner already said, the access to the local filesystem is actually very limited due to security restrictions

Comment: Yeah I looked at that before, but that's not exactly what I want, take a look at the update

Answer (score 0):

If you meant a file stored on your local computer, you will have to create a program using languages like C, C++, or maybe even PHP if you create a local webserver. Accessing files on your computer just using a html or JavaScript is not possible.
As your question is not quite clear, maybe a file input is what you are looking for, like Jeroen answered. Then you can maybe use JavaScript to determine the path of the selected file... Although, as you said you were good in JavaScript, you probably already known that.

Comment: Would it be possible to check if a file exists in a folder via JS? Maybe just get the file's path copied into the clipboard and the user can manually open Outlook and paste the path to the file?

Comment: Also, take a look at the update as I think my idea is clear now of what I want to do

Comment: No sry you can't check if a local file exists via JS.

Comment: What about on a ftp server?

Comment: Well that's possible, if you run a FTP server on your computer. But it's only possible using PHP not just JavaScript...